# My activity when in background for several time stops operating

Tags: android, service, android-activity, background, lifecycle

I have one activity that starts several services in handlers some have their own threads to execute work in background.

When the activity is placed in background for like 15 minutes it is still there and i can get to it but it stops updating the textviews.

Why this happens?

Comment: If I understood correctly you want code in the Activity being executed while activity is in the background? When the activity enterers the onPaused() any code stops executing. If you want anything to be performed while the user is anywhere else but in your activity you'd have to use a Service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your activity is in the background, android pauses it and may stop and destroy it to free resources should need be.
You should just make sure that the textviews are updated when the onResume() for the activity is fired.